# Reg ex for PORTION of URL

Tags: regex, url, vbscript

I am awful at regex unless it's all literal.  Here's a sample of the blob I'm working with:

watch/video/713546/pope-prays-for-victims-of-chinese-port-explosions',rating:'5.0'},{title:'Tianjin Blasts: \'\'It\'s Like a Ghost Town\'',thumbnail:'http%3A%2F%2Fpthumbnails.5min.com%2F10380295%2F519014715_c_140_105.jpg',durationTime:'1:50',url:'/watch/video/713622/tianjin-blasts-its-like-a-ghost-town',rating:'0.0'},{title:'Residents Concerned Over Tianjin Environment After Deadly Blasts',thumbnail:'http%3A%2F%2Fpthumbnails.5min.com%2F10380307%2F519015303_3.jpg',durationTime:'1:19',url:'/watch/video/713889/residents-concerned-over-tianjin-environment-after-deadly-blasts',rating:'0.0'},{title:'Families of Missing Fire Fighters Demand Answers in Tianjin',thumbnail:'http%3A%2F%2Fpthumbnails

**Need to grab this data from above:**

Example 1: `/watch/video/713889/residents-concerned-over-tianjin-environment-after-deadly-blasts`

Example 2: `/watch/video/713622/tianjin-blasts-its-like-a-ghost-town`

It sits between the `''` in `url:''`.

So far I have this for my regex: `url:'/`

To clarify what I'm after, I want everything AFTER the url:'

Example of desired output: 
/watch/video/710284/google-to-become-subsidiary-of-alphabet
/watch/video/699946/what-is-googles-project-jacquard

Also, I'm getting these URL's: 
Url:'/watch'
Url:'/games'

Maybe we can set it so I get everything after: url:'/watch/video   ?

So, if the string is: `/watch/video/713889/residents-concerned-over-tianjin-environment-after-deadly-blasts`

I'd just want: /video/713889/residents-concerned-over-tianjin-environment-after-deadly-blasts

Comment: Realized the portion I pasted is missing the first "/" from "/watch/video/713546/pope-prays-for-victims-of-chinese-port-explosions"

Comment: The data you're working with looks like JSON. Would PowerShell be an option for you?

Comment: So, let's be clear. All of the elements that you want will have the form `url:'/watch/video/` and you only want to capture from `/video` onwards?

Comment: Close.  It's also capturing THESE tiny url's: Url:'/watch'  Url:'/games'.  So I'm thinking, let's have it capture everything PAST this literal: Url:'/watch/  (and before the last ' in the url - the end ' should NOT be captured)  Output example: video/23946/5-hottest-places-on-earth

Comment: OK, I've updated the regex. try it now. Same link.

Comment: Working.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you say, your data was mangled, but I fixed it and have a regex working for you.

```
>?url:\'\/watch\/(video[\w-\/]*)'
```

will capture what you want. I can't help you implement it in vbscript, but the regex will work. The target is in a group so you will need to get the group out of your match object. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/yT5dP2/1) is a link to the regex101 working.

Comment: See clarified (edited) request in OP.  I'm looking for everything AFTER the url:' piece.  Sorry!

Comment: I can make this work.  It's still outputting the url:' and trailing ', but I took off the trailing ' and can use the replace function to find url:' and replace with the front of the URL (http portion).  This works for me using >?url:\'\/watch\/(video[\w-\/]*)    Thanks!